# Sort of multidimensional array in php without a key?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to sort a multidimensional array in numerical order bu second value of each item.

This is array:

```
$vulc = array(
        array('s',3),
        array('s',5),
        array('s',2)
    );
```

and i want this output:

```
$vulc = array(
        array('s',5),
        array('s',3),           
        array('s',2)
    );
```

I'm tried this:

```
foreach ($vulc as $key => $row) {
    $distance[$key] = $row[2];
}

array_multisort($distance, SORT_ASC, $vulc);
```

but doesn't work :( please help me and not suggest to see other answer... usually other answer are too difficult :(

Comment: I'm gonna ignore your "other answer" remark and link this, since it really can't get any less difficult than this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value

Comment: I already closed your last question and in the duplicate there are multiple solutions how to solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17364127/3933332 I can't make the answer more obvious.

Comment: @Rizier123 i know and i see your linked question... but for me is too difficult understand the accepted answer in there question: is difficult beacause is big, i'm not able with php e because i'm italian and don't understand english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the usort function and Try:

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $b[1] - $a[1]; // $b[1] - $a[1] because it need to be descending order
}

usort($vulc, 'sortByOrder');
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => s
            [1] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => s
            [1] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => s
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `rsort()`

```
$vulc = array(
        array('s',3),
        array('s',5),
        array('s',2)
    );
rsort($vulc);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($vulc);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => s
            [1] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => s
            [1] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => s
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort, and add 's' to sorted array:

```
<?php
$vulc = array(
    array('s',3),
    array('s',5),
    array('s',2)
);

foreach ($vulc as $key => $row) {
    $distance[] = $row[1];
}

array_multisort($distance, SORT_ASC, $vulc);

foreach ($distance as $row) {
    $vulcOut[] = ['s', $row];
}

// $vulcOut = array(
//     array('s',5),
//     array('s',3),
//     array('s',2)
// );
```